# Uninstall/Reinstall leiningen(clojure server) related issues

Tags: installation, clojure, leiningen

As I asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359388/leiningen-related-commands-too-slow-with-mac-os-x), I found that running '**sudo** lein deps causes some problem that forces me to run '**sudo** lein swank', which is annoying. And [I was told not to use **sudo**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343555/running-clojure-with-lein-swank-on-aquamacs-problem) I use Mac OS X 10.6.4.

So, I'll try to uninstall and reinstall leiningen.

#### Uninstalling leiningen

- Removing ~/.m2 directory is just uninstall, is this correct?

#### (Re)installing leiningen

I followed the steps explained [here](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).

1. copy the 'lein' to ~/bin/lein and make it runnable.
2. Run 'lein self-install', and I see ~/.m2/repository is installed.
3. download leiningen using 'http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen.git' to ~/bin/leinigen

   - At this stage, I can't run 'lein help', but '**sudo** lein help'. What's wrong with this?
4. As a result, I can't run 'lein deps', but '**sudo** lein deps, and the problem becomes recursive one.

#### Questions

- Q : How to uninstall perfectly with leiningen?
- Q : Why using 'sudo' makes lein correctly?

Comment: I think this is off-topic and belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: this question is about how to use a code generation+compiler+ide it is more suited to stack overflow than serverfault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes removing .m2 and then  `lein self-install` should fix this :)

when you can sudo lein ... it created files in .m2 owned by root so removing these and then recreating them as the proper user (you) should fix it. you could perhaps also just change the user on them back to yourself.

```
chown username:users ~/.m2/*
```