# lein swank doesn't work after lein upgrade

Tags: clojure, leiningen, swank-clojure

After upgrading Leiningen (from v1.6 to v1.7) with `lein upgrade` command `lein swank` stopped working with error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
[...] 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class:  .  Program will exit.
```

Since I tried it from command line, I believe Emacs configuration doesn't matter in this case. So I tried to re-install Leiningen completely. What I've done (using suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363681/uninstall-reinstall-leiningenclojure-server-related-issues) and error messages):

```
rm -R ~/.m2
# rm ~/.lein/plugins/*  
lein self-install
```

(I used second line on second reinstallation only, so it is here for the sake of completeness)

Then I created new project and installed lein-swank plugin, since, as far as I understand, it is recommended way at the moment:

```
lein new test-project
lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.4.0  # I tried earlier version (1.3.2) too
```

And finally started lein swank with:

```
cd test-project
lein swank
```

But got same error as before.

So my questions are:

1. How to fix this problem?
2. Do I reinstall Leiningen correctly or some steps are missing?

**UPD.** Here's `project.clj` generated with new project:

```
(defproject test-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
   :description "FIXME: write description"
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]])
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message say what class was not found? Could you please add that to your post. Also, can you please post your `project.clj` file.

Comment: @liwp: Nope, the error message was just as in a snippet - no class, just space and the dot. `project.clj` was generated by Leiningen and had no modifications. Completely fresh project. Note that from that time I moved to another laptop and there fresh Leinigen installation worked perfectly.

Comment: I'd still like to see whether your `project.clj` specifies Clojure 1.2.1 or 1.3.0.

Comment: @liwp: it is 1.3.0. See my update for full `project.clj` (if that still makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the swank-clojure [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure) help:

> Troubleshooting
>
> Currently having multiple versions of swank-clojure on
>   the classpath can cause issues when running lein swank or lein
>   jack-in. It's recommended to not put swank-clojure in your
>   :dev-dependencies but run lein plugin install to have it installed
>   globally for all projects instead. This also means that people hacking
>   on your project won't have to pull it in if they are not Emacs users.
>
> It's also possible for some packages to pull in old versions of
>   swank-clojure transitively, so check the lib/ directory if you are
>   having issues. In particular, Incanter is known to exhibit this
>   problem. Judicious use of :exclusions make it work:
>
> ```
> :dependencies [[incanter "1.2.3" :exclusions [swank-clojure]]]
> ```
>
> Since swank-clojure 1.3.4, having versions of clj-stacktrace older
>   than 0.2.1 in your project or user-level plugins will cause Unable to
>   resolve symbol: pst-elem-str errors. Keep in mind that user-level
>   plugins in ~/.lein/plugins are uberjars in Leiningen 1.x, so it's
>   possible that one of your plugins (such as lein-difftest before
>   version 1.3.7) contains an old clj-stacktrace even if it doesn't have
>   its own file there. Specifying a newer version should be enough if
>   you're having trouble:
>
> ```
> :dependencies [[clj-stacktrace "0.2.4"]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I already mentioned I reinstalled Leinigen and had created completely new project. Thus these suggestions are not applicable (unless there is some dependency of Leiningen left that I haven't noticed). Anyway, upvote for relevant answer.

Comment: I remember having to add `clj-stacktrace` as a dependency at some point in the recent past to get things to work, but that doesn't seem to be necessary any more with Leiningen 1.7.0 and swank-clojure 1.4.0. Sorry I can't be of more help. I'd suggest deleting everything like you did before, including the `lein` script, and starting from scratch.